# How to connect frontend with contract backend using truffle?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, ipfs

Right now I'm having some trouble understanding how it all fits together if I want to make a Dapp.

I did create a contract and the frontend using truffle. Then I compiled it and deployed it to Ropsten with the Browser Solidity and I think that the next step is to download the Ropsten blockchain with Geth.

Then deploy the contract with truffle, then I'll be able to host my files in IPFS and use a DNS to get a decent domain to that Dapp.

The problem is **I'm not understanding how I'm supposed to connect my frontend app with the contract in the testnet Ropsten using truffle**. Thank you again for your effords.

Comment: check this URL. I think this question has been answered. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13128/how-to-build-a-front-end-for-dapp